# Thin clients video in LTSP changed when adding a new video card to the server

Tags: 10.10, nvidia, ltsp

First of all I'm new in using linux and please forgive my bad english.

I have an server with Edubuntu LTSP 10.10, a projector and 20 thin clients. On the server I had to install a video card (nvidia chipset driver 260.19.06) with two ports: DVI and VGA so I can connect the projector on the VGA port. After I installed the driver I managed to configure display settings in twinview clones.

Till now everything is ok but now comes the strange part..until I had to install the video card when users login on thin clients their display was normal but now it is mirrored and upside down and I don't know what happened. Can anyone please tell what to do get display to normal?

Comment: Good question, possibly a bug.  Unfortunately I have no idea +1 to question.  Have you tried the open source driver?

Answer (score 1):

Disable Compiz and reboot everything.

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1154859)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi I'm really sorry that the answer was not sufficient enough. But I have provided link for reference and I do not any any other info... I hope that this "answer" saved him a lot of searching and thus it was helpful...